# Meaning of "get out" in "He gets out when he can"

Tags: slang, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs, idiom-meaning, lyrics

In his famous hit *Working Class Man*, Jimmy Barnes [sings](https://youtu.be/t3TPmPOrDEk?t=58):

> He believes in God and Elvis
>
> He gets out when he can
>
> He did his time in Vietnam
>
> Still mad at Uncle Sam

I can't make sense of the second line. What could it mean? What does he get out of?

I thought that the line in question might be some idiom or slang known among workers, so I looked in dictionaries, but found no idiom or slang that would fit the context.

Maybe it's something obvious to native speakers, but I am not one.

I humbly hope that users of this SE can shed light on this mystery.

Comment: The first hit in a Google search for "get out" + meaning: << get out (of something)
to leave or go out of a place: _You ought to get out of the house more._ /  _She screamed at me to get out._  See _get out_ in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

get out phrasal verb - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course I saw that meaning, but I had no idea what exactly he gets out of. The answer below explains that this phrase is used in this song figuratively rather than literally, and it makes sense to me now

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get_out) makes it very clear: << **get out**:  
(intransitive) To spend free time out of the house. _You work too hard. You should get out more._ >>

Comment: A lot of the lyrics of that song seem very vague - perhaps intentionally so. Which makes it hard to say what the precise meaning is in this song - does it mean he's not a stay-at-home type, not someone who does domestic activities or stays in reading and thinking, someone who goes out drinking or socialising or doing outdoor pursuits (hunting, sports, driving) or doing some other kind of thing? That's probably a question for another forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Get out* is just a phrasal verb meaning "to go out, to spend time outside". *OED* lists the relevant sense of *get out* including the figurative sense as below:

> To leave one's home or lodgings for some purpose, esp. habitually. Hence *figurative*: to mix with other people frequently (chiefly in the negative, esp. in *to not get out much*, with the implication that a person is out of touch).
>
> <sub>*Oxford English Dictionary*, s.v. “'to get out' in get, v., sense 1.c”, July 2023. 
> https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/6423441165</sub>